# How can I add a header to the NSIS license page?

Tags: nsis

The top of my NSIS license page looks rather stark:

[image]

I don't see any way to modify the header/subtitle of the page through the normal channels.  [`LicenseText`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.8.1.28) looks close, but it only seems to modify the text at the *bottom* of the dialog.

Is there any way to add a header to the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must include a language to fully initialize the MUI:

```
!include "MUI.nsh"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "License.rtf"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_...
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
```

If you want to use a bitmap in the header and not the .exe icon, then you should look at the defines Seki talks about...

Comment: I do have `!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"` in there.  (All other text in the installer works well.)

Comment: Oh really?  Well that's good to know.  I probably am just doing something wrong..  Edit: Indeed, I was using [`Page license`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter2.html#2.3.2) rather than `MUI_PAGE_..`.  Once I copied the code above it worked fine, sigh.  Thanks very much for your patience!

Comment: Random images from google: Icon: http://seclists.org/nmap-dev/2008/q1/att-461/nsis_license_page.png (Included) Bitmap: http://img.brothersoft.com/screenshots/softimage/n/nsis-72725-1.jpeg

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Modern UI, define `MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP` to the path of an image (you can see in the [MUI documentation](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Modern%20UI/Readme.html).

You have an example in the script `HeaderBitmap.nsi` that comes with MUI2.

Comment: I don't want to change the header on all of my installer screens - just the license page.  (The rest of them all have pleasant titles and subtitles in that area.)

Comment: I have never tried that, but you could redefine the header to the specific bitmap just before the `!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE` and redefine it after to the previous value?

Comment: I'm afraid it won't let me `!define` the same constant more than once: *!define: "MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP" already defined!*.  Thanks anyway!